# when use eda(display_format = 'bokeh') from pycaret with jupyterlab ,the bokeh plot cannot change by selecting different var

Tags: jupyter-lab, pycaret

when use eda(display_format = 'bokeh') from pycaret with jupyterlab ,the bokeh plot cannot change by selecting different var.But it run smoothly in notebook.[the plot like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UMu2.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

AutoViz is an optional dependency in pycaret and hence, this issue should be filed in [the AutoViz repo](https://github.com/AutoViML/AutoViz).